# Table.dbo object?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a record but I get an exception.  Any ideas?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        string _query = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('MS','AH','BOSS')";
        DataSet _ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {

            using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_query, _conn);
                _conn.Open();
                _da.Fill(_ds);
            }

            // insert null dataset or invalid return logic (too many tables, too few columns/rows, etc here. 


            if (_ds.Tables.Count == 1)
            { //There is a table, assign the name to it.
                MessageBox.Show("1");
                _ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
            }

            //Then work with your tblWorkers 
            MessageBox.Show(_ds.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Console.Write("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
        } 
    }
```

how can i add a record to the table?? data type is nchar

Comment: Wow. You realy didn't understand the concept here... You use SqlCommand to execute insert, update or delete on the database and not SqlAdapter.Fill().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string _connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string _query = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('MS','AH','BOSS')";

    using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand _com = _conn.CreateCommand();
        _conn.Open();
        _com.CommandText = _query;
        _com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

In general:

- SqlDataAdapter (and DataSet.Fill method) are used for reading data in first turn (and update loaded data set in case you change it). Read [MSDN on this subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)
- SqlCommand is used for executing sql queries

Answer (score 0):

additionally your INSERT command will only work if you have 3 fields in your table.  If you have more than three fields you need to explicitly declare which three fields you want to insert those values into.

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES ('MS','AH','BOSS')
```